# display image while loading external page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Am using script to load external page(external means page in my website) inside div so am using following script to load page since loading page take time so i need to display image until page is loaded

### SCRIPT

```
       function HideLoader() {
                $('#loader').css('display', 'none');
            }

            function ShowLoader() {
                $('#loader').css('display', '');
            }


            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('.reveal').on('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    ShowLoader();
                    var link = $(this).attr('href');
                    $('.page').load(link);
                    $('#leftmenu').css('width', '70px');
                    $("#leftmenu b,li ul").hide();
                    $('li').unbind('click');
                    $(this).show();
                    HideLoader();
                });
            });
```

### CSS

```
#loader {
  display: unset;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 100px;

}
```

### HTML

```
<div id="loader"> <img src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading" /> </div>
```

ERROR is it display image before clicking link

i want the image to display when i click link and disappear when page is loaded

Comment: Are you trying to load a page in an iframe within your current page? Does the page completely cover the image when it is finished loading?

Comment: no not in iframe within page inside a div, my problem is images is displayed before clicking load

Comment: Add the `hidden` attribute to the img tag and toggle it with your js?

Comment: @Grice where to add `hidden` attribute ?? `$('#loader').css('display', 'none');` this place???

Comment: in your CSS, set the display to none, so it doesn't show. Then in your click function, set it to display inline, block, inherit...whichever is appropriate. Then on completion of the load (callback), set it back to display:none.

Comment: still doest works image is displayed before clicking link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain...

CSS **change to display:none**:

```
#loader {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 100px;

}
```

Javascript
Change this:

```
function ShowLoader() {
    $('#loader').css('display', 'block');
}
```

and this:

```
 $('.reveal').on('click', function(e) {
        var $that = $(this);

        e.preventDefault();
        ShowLoader();
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.page').load(link, function(){
             HideLoader(); // this puts it in the load callback, so that this stuff
             $that.show(); // happens when the load is complete
        });
        $('#leftmenu').css('width', '70px');
        $("#leftmenu b,li ul").hide();
        $('li').unbind('click');
    });
```

Comment: when i click link external page will be loaded that time i need to display image and disaapear when page loaded but in your code image is displayed before clicking

Comment: that's why you need to set it to display:none by default in your CSS. You want it to never display till the javascript function tells it to. 'unset' is not valid css and therefor is ignored by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your div is always visible. You need to change your css to have it not visible by default:

```
#loader {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 100px;

}
```

`display: unset` simply uses the default value for the tag, which is visible.

You will also need to change your `showLoader` function to:

```
function ShowLoader() {
    $('#loader').css('display', 'block');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, in your showLoader function, set the display value to 'block'