# how to display image full screan untile load page complet?

Tags: html, css, dom

I have website and since loading page take time so i need to display image until page is loaded .

how can i do?
I find [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57636727/display-full-page-overlay-on-page-load) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27427978/display-image-while-loading-external-page) but I'm more confused now.
my pic is [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is removed when the page is loaded.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.querySelector("#loading-img").remove();
})
```

```css
#loading-img {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999999;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<img id="loading-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6RWO.gif" />
```

Or you can set any specific time for remove the image.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector("#loading-img").remove();
}, 2000); // remove img after 2 seconds
```

```css
#loading-img {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999999;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<img id="loading-img" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6RWO.gif" />
```